# How to specify [Now] in content query web part

Tags: content-query-web-part

I currently have a content query web part that has a filter on it to show items that have a published date less than or equal to [Today] and it works great.

The problem is I'd like to change this filter to be time based as well as day.  I tried putting [Now] in the filter box, but it doesn't allow it.

Can anyone let me know how to change it from day based filter to time based filtering?

[image: Current Setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and had to go into Sharepoint Designer to apply a query override:

```
QueryOverride="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='PubDate' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='PubDate' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' StorageTZ='TRUE'><Today /></Value></Leq></Where>"
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897399%28v=office.12%29.aspx) details a fix without SPD, it's for 2007 but it can be done in other versions as well.

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you!  Any idea how I would add in the query to show only the last 10 posts as well?